# MySQL GROUP BY date when using datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

In MySQL, let's say I have a table with a column called 'actionTime' declared as a 'datetime' (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

Is there an easy way to use "GROUP BY actionTime" but only use the 'date' part of the 'datetime'?

Thanks

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/mysql-sql-group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should be able to

```
GROUP BY date(actionTime)
```

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
        -> '2003-12-31'
```

Comment: Google is easy to use. But the whole point of stackoverflow is getting a peer-reviewed solution

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use MySQL's [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fdate) function:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table GROUP BY DATE(actionTime);
```