# How to create a query for monthly total in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have the following DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `omc_order` (
  `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `delivery_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `payment_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=32;
```

I want to create a statistic page to see total payment and total order monthly.

In one page I want to display something like this.

```
Month    Year    Total Order    Total Payment
Sep       09       800             760
Oct       09       670             876
Nov
...
...
```

Now I am not sure how to create query for this.

Could anyone give me some ideas how to approach this?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'total order' was meant to be just a count of orders?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Mysql date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to group the rows for each month and them sum them up. Something like this could be a starting point:

```
  SELECT monthname(payment_date) AS Month,
         year(payment_date) AS Year,
         sum(total) AS 'Total Order',
         sum(??) AS 'Total Payment'
    FROM omc_order
ORDER BY payment_date
GROUP BY month(payment_date),
         year(payment_date);
```

I'm not sure how you compute the values for `Total Payment`.

**Edit**: `sum()` is a [MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Comment: Do I need to add sum feild in DB?

Comment: @shin Nope that is a function in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

you need to Cast the datetime to a mount , then group by

```
SELECT SUM(foo), MONTH(mydate) DateOnly FROM a_table GROUP BY DateOnly;
```

see a close question :

[MySQL/SQL: Group by date only on a Datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/mysql-sql-group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column)

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you get started.

```
select sum(total) from omc_order group by month(order_date), year(order_date)
```