# MySQL select using datetime, group by date only

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

Is is possible to select a datetime field from a MySQL table and group by the date only?

I'm trying to output a list of events that happen at multiple times, grouped by the date it happened on.

My table/data looks like this: (**the timestamp is a datetime field**)

```
1. 2010-03-21 18:00:00  Event1
2. 2010-03-21 18:30:00  Event2
3. 2010-03-30 13:00:00  Event3
4. 2010-03-30 14:00:00  Event4
```

I want to output something like this:

```
March 21st
1800 - Event 1
1830 - Event 2

March 30th
1300 - Event 3
1400 - Event 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/mysql-sql-group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%H%i'), DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%M %D'), event FROM table ORDER BY date_column
```

`%H%i - 1830`

`%M%D - March 21st`

Answer (score 5):

select date_format(created_at, "%Y-m-%d") as date  from tablename GROUP BY date

OR

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%H%i') as time,  event FROM table ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y-%m-%d'), time