# Iterating array/hashmap

Tags: php, mysql

Edit: Nico Parodi's answer is correct. I will eventually return to finding out why, but for now I will just take it as it is and hope nothing else fails.

I have a table with three fields: "date", "name", "location". I want to group all the records selected from this table based on their date.

By copy-pasting some code from [php mysql group by date with yyyy-mm-dd format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711033/php-mysql-group-by-date-with-yyyy-mm-dd-format), I've managed to get this array, date -> name:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, name, location FROM events");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $foo[$row['date']][]=$row['name'];
}
```

Everything's great, I can iterate it without issues. Now I want to store all the row columns as a value for the date key, so I try to store the entire row as a value:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, name, location FROM events");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $foo[$row['date']][]=$row;
}
```

And now I can't iterate it. count($rowCol) seems to give me the nr of columns in all the array for either keys, not just for one. How can I iterate it?

```
foreach($foo as $date => $events) {
    echo $date . ": "; // this is okay         

    foreach($events as $key => $rowCol){
        for ($i = 0; $i<count($rowCol); $i++) {
            echo $rowCol[$i] . " ";     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit, I can't see it - this is a simplified version of my code. The actual one compiles/runs fine.

Comment: @Buffalo Here: `$row['date'])]`

Comment: Yes, good spot! I had a substr() call there.

Comment: use `var_dump($events);` under `echo $date . ":";` and post the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($rowCol); $i++) {
    echo $rowCol[$i] . " ";     
}
```

$rowCol has the double of fields that you expect as mysqli_fetch_array() fetches as both associative and numeric array.
So,

```
for ($i = 0; $i<(count($rowCol)/2); $i++) {
        echo $rowCol[$i] . " ";     
    }
```

should work.

Comment: Because mysqli_fetch_row() fetches only as numeric array so you now have the number of fields you always expected, so in this case you don't have to use count($rowCol)/2, just use as before, count($rowCol).

Comment: use var_dump($rowCol) to print the array and see why it has the double of fields

Comment: Minor question: can I also get the key when I'm iterating? the name of the table column?

Comment: yes, to do it you should change mysqli_fetch_array call to [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) to fetch results into only associative array - and then you can use `foreach ($rowCol as $colName=>$val)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us what's the output of this code? (show plain text, no HTML):

```
foreach($foo as $date => $event) {
    echo $date . ": ";

    foreach($event as $key => $value){
        print_r($value);
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

---

Original answer:

`$events` contains a single event, your code should look more like this:

```
foreach($foo as $date => $event) {
    echo $date . ": ";

    foreach($event as $key => $value){
        echo $value . " ";
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: This prints out "2001-02: Array 2012-02: Array 2012-03: Array 2013-03: Array Array".

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($rowCol); $i++) {
        echo $rowCol[$i] . " ";     
    }
```

this part of code doesn't work because rowCol is an associative array + numeric array. Try to replace mysqli_fetch_array with mysqli_fetch_row

Comment: Mind posting the appropriate foreach? believe me, I've tried to no avail.

Comment: update: my fault, try to replace mysqli_fetch_array with mysqli_fetch_row

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($rowCol); $i++) {
        echo $rowCol[$i] . " ";     
    }
```

By

```
    foreach($rowCol as $k =>$v) {
        echo $v . " ";     
    }
```