# How to select unique visitors per date interval?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I've found a few query strings related to what I'm looking for, but nothing that does this.  Basically, I have a graph that needs to display unique visitors per time interval (hour, day, month, or year).  So, a graph similar to Google Analytics or [this Analytics Graph](http://demo.openwebanalytics.com/owa/).  The table has a visitor ID column and a timestamp column (in the style 0000-00-00 00:00:00).  I need to be able to select the unique or total visitors per interval (eg. 32 visitors on the 5th, 30 on the 6th, etc).

I guess my question is, is there anyway to do this efficiently with just a query?  Or will I need to use PHP to get all the data (problem with that is that I would have to do a query for each point on the graph, not efficient)?

Comment: All you need is: `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()`, `DATE()`

Comment: Looks pretty much like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/mysql-sql-group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to aggregate your data. Try this query:

```
SELECT DATE(data_timestamp), COUNT(visitor_id)
FROM analytics_table
WHERE DATE(data_timestamp) BETWEEN '2011-05-01' AND '2011-05-31'
GROUP BY 1
```

Here's how you populate your monthly data (**WARNING: UNTESTED!**):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DATE(data_timestamp), COUNT(visitor_id)
FROM analytics_table
WHERE DATE(data_timestamp) BETWEEN '2011-05-01' AND '2011-05-31'
GROUP BY 1";

$rs = mysql_query($rs);
$date1 = $datex = '2011-05-01';
$date2 = '2011-05-31';

$arrayData = $tmpArray = array();

while( $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs) )
{
   $tmpArray[$r['date']] = $r['count'];
}

while( $datex <= $date2)
{
   if( isset($tmpArray[$datex]) )
   {
      $arrayData[$datex] = $tmpArray[$datex];
   }
   else
   {
      $arrayData[$datex] = 0;
   }
   list( $y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $datex);
   $datex = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y));
}


?>
```

this query use:

- DATE() to get the date from your data and
- COUNT() to count total data from that particular date.
- and GROUP BY to group your data based on what field you select.

Comment: That's a simple version of what I had tried, but that doesn't solve the problem of getting the values for each day (or month or year).  For example, the graph should show 1 month of activity with the number of unique users per day.

Comment: @zerkms: ooops, my bad. should be `GROUP BY 1`

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help.  We ended up using:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id), DATE(time) FROM tracking_pageview WHERE site_id='$this->site_id' AND DATE(time) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $days DAY) GROUP BY DATE(time)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can cast the DATETIME/TIMESTAMP into dates, and times separately, and then use a GROUP BY to get the results you need.

[MySQL/SQL: Group by date only on a Datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/mysql-sql-group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column)

Comment: How does one use that with a date interval?  (Eg. total each day for 1 month)

Comment: Cast it to a DATE only (which drops the time - 1/1/01, 1/2/01, 1/3/01, etc.), and in the SQL statement you COUNT(*) and GROUP BY the date alone.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY doesn't return 0 value if there is no visitor some day. That will yield to the holes in time continuity. There are two ways:

1) Group like others said and then find holes

2) Create aggregation table with fields "date", "count" etc. and insert there data every day by cron.