# Group by the date part of a timestamp field

Tags: mysql, group-by, timestamp

I have `users` table. I would like to generate a report of user who joined for that day. 
Problem is, my `DateJoined` field is a `timestamp` field,

**As the query is following as:**

```
SELECT COUNT(UserID) AS TOT FROM users GROUP BY DateJoined
```

does not work, how do I get it to `GROUP BY` just the date part and not the time of `DateJoined` field?

Comment: @jmail: I appreciate your intention to format posts to make them convey the message properly to the end user. But I still suggest you to sign up at [*English Language Learners*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) and gain some reputation.

Comment: @Ravinder, thanks for suggestion And definitely I'll sign up in the `ELL`..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL/SQL: Group by date only on a Datetime column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/mysql-sql-group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

***your code:***

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(UserID) AS TOT 
      FROM users 
      GROUP BY DateJoined
```

***you should change like as:***

```
SELECT 
       DATE(DateJoined), 
       COUNT(UserID) AS TOT 
       FROM users 
       GROUP BY DATE(DateJoined)
```

***the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91b6c/3)***

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This

```
 SELECT COUNT(UserID) AS TOT FROM users GROUP BY CAST(DateJoined AS DATE)
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(UserID) AS TOT, FROM a_table GROUP BY DATE(DateJoined );
```

Answer (score 1):

use query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(UserID) AS TOT FROM users GROUP BY DATE(DateJoined)
```