# How to show all time records from two tables day wise

Tags: mysql

I have below given mysql query to output required records for single day. It is working perfectly. But i want to show all time records from two table day wise. my two tables have unix timestamps

Query for single day records is

```
    // DAY DATA STATS
$stmt_check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM webstats WHERE pubhash =? AND time BETWEEN $day6 AND $day5");
$stmt_check->bind_param("s", $pubhash);
$stmt_check->execute();
$stmt_check->store_result();
$numberofrowsimpresssday = $stmt_check->num_rows;

$stmt_check->close();

$sql2 = "SELECT SUM(click) AS click_sum FROM webstatsclick WHERE pubhash='$pubhash' AND time BETWEEN $day6 AND $day5";
         $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

$clickz = $row['click_sum'];
$clicks = $clickz ?: '0';

            }
         } else {

         }

?>
<br>
<?php echo $day6; ?>||<?php echo $numberofrowsimpresssday; ?>||<?php echo $clicks; ?>
<?php
// DAY STATS ENDS
```

This should output AS 1542758400||113||2  where 
 DAY MIDNIGHT TIMESTAMP||IMPRESSIONS||CLICKS

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

New updated code

```
$sql2 = "SELECT 
    count(*) as 'impressions',
    unix_timestamp(date(from_unixtime(A.time))) as 'timestamp',
    sum(click) as 'clicks'
FROM `webadstats` as A
LEFT JOIN `webstatsclick` as B
ON A.pubadhash = B.pubadhash
WHERE A.pubadhash='$pubadhash'
GROUP BY date(from_unixtime(A.time))";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $impressions[] = $row['impressions'];
        $clicksall[] = $row['clicks'];
        $timestamp[] = $row['timestamp'];
    }


   for($i=0; $i<count($clicksall); $i++){
    $str .= $timestamp[$i] . '||' . $impressions[$i] . '||' . $clicksall[$i] . ',';
    }
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking can be solved with GROUP BY and the DATE() function. See this question: [MySQL/SQL: Group by date only on a Datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/mysql-sql-group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column)

You also need to use from_unixtime() in order to convert the timestamp into a date. See this question: 
[Convert Unix timestamp into human readable date using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql)

```
SELECT count(*),
       unix_timestamp(date(from_unixtime(time))) as 'timestamp' 
FROM webstats 
WHERE pubhash =? 
GROUP BY date(from_unixtime(time))

SELECT SUM(click) AS 'click_sum',
       unix_timestamp(date(from_unixtime(time))) as 'timestamp' 
FROM webstatsclick 
WHERE pubhash='$pubhash' 
GROUP BY date(from_unixtime(time))
```

Edit: To help with your specific case, your PHP code can be cleaned up and you can do everything in one query instead of two. See below:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT 
    count(*) as 'impressions',
    unix_timestamp(date(from_unixtime(A.time))) as 'timestamp',
    sum(B.click) as 'clicks'
FROM `webstats` as A
LEFT JOIN `webstatsclick` as B
ON A.pubhash = B.pubhash
WHERE A.pubhash='$pubhash'
GROUP BY date(from_unixtime(A.time))";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $impressions[] = $row['impressions']
        $clicksall[] = $row['clicks'];
        $timestamp[] = $row['timestamp'];
    }
    while($i=0; $i<strlen($clicksall); $i++){
        $str .= '<br>' . $timestamp[$i] . '||' . $impressions[$i] . '||' . $clicksall[$i];
    }
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how to output DAY MIDNIGHT TIMESTAMP parameter as discussed above in my question

Comment: If I understand your question, then the updated code should work. Here is an example result using this sort of query on my database: https://i.imgur.com/NtsMAia.png

Comment: no its not working, it producing only single record for last day date

Comment: Could you explain what results you are getting? Is it just 1 row, is it returning multiple rows but the date is wrong? Or something else?

Comment: plz check my code https://ibb.co/KLC8M3M. it shows only single day 24 nov day data but not all time

Comment: First, I don't understand why you are using two different query methods. Dealing with their results will inevitably be different on the php side. Second, the results are not one row, but your loop is dealing with one variable and overwriting the results on each pass of the loop. That's why your result just shows you the last result. I'll type up a longer php code, give me a few minutes please.

Comment: My updated code should be able to replace the entire portion which you showed in your screenshot.

Comment: Mark, you need to provide more details. Please show the code as you did before (so I can see line numbers) and then please show the exact error.

Comment: Jared i have updated my question with new code, I have rectified its syntex error but i have issue, this code is generating same values for both $impressions[$i] and $clicksall[$i] variables. Kindly help

Comment: Is the value for impressions correct, or clicks? Can you please tell me the data structure for the click column in the webstatsclick table?

Comment: The value of impressions is correct. The table webadstats contains impressions data and webstatsclic clicks data which has columns srno, pubadhash,time and click column having value 1.

Comment: Try changing sum(B.click) to count(B.click)

Comment: Tried both with sum(B.click) to count(B.click)  but still issue persists

Comment: Can you please show some rows of your database? The code works for me when I test with my own tables

Comment: Plz mail me your email at psjallah1@gmail.com so that we can discuss there

Comment: After reviewing the images you sent me and the code which works on my reproduced tables, I wonder if your click column is set to some default value and if that is influencing the result. Instead of count(B.click) try count(B.visitorip). If that still doesn't work, please screenshot the entire section of code once again.

Comment: Jared plz check emailed screenshots

Comment: What happens if you change `ON A.pubadhash = B.pubadhash` to `ON A.session = B.session` ?