# MySQL count elements and group by date, ignore time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table storing payment transactions. They are stored with datetime in this way:

```
day-month-year hour:min:sec (Example: 18-11-2019 11:54:41)
```

I want to count how many transactions per day.

If I use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), paid FROM `payments` WHERE paid IS NOT NULL GROUP BY paid
```

it returns me every single row, but I want to group by date, ignoring time.

Comment: @CherryDT nothing works, maybe because my date format is european?

Comment: You said it is "stored with datetime" - I assumed you mean it is a `DATETIME` column, then you'd just use `GROUP BY DATE(paid)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL/SQL: Group by date only on a Datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/mysql-sql-group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column)

Comment: Store data using the appropriate data type for that data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your column in an actual `DATETIME`, the `DATE` function should do:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id), paid FROM `payments` WHERE paid IS NOT NULL GROUP BY DATE(paid)
```

If it is a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` with a custom format, like the example you specified (`18-11-2019 11:54:41`), you'd need to parse it first using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id), paid FROM `payments` WHERE paid IS NOT NULL GROUP BY DATE(STR_TO_DATE(paid, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'))
```

Comment: Plainly, it's not a datetime column

Answer (score 2):

You should always use the `DATETIME` column format to store dates, not `VARCHAR`. You can always deal with presentation issues (e.g. converting to European format) in your application layer. If that was the case you could simply `GROUP BY DATE(paid)` i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(id), paid 
FROM `payments` 
WHERE paid IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY DATE(paid)
```

If your column is `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` you need to convert it to a value you can group by. If the format is `DD-MM-YYYY`, you can simply use `LEFT(paid, 10)` to extract the date portion and group by that i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(id), paid 
FROM `payments` 
WHERE paid IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY LEFT(paid, 10)
```

If you're dates are stored as `D-M-YYYY` you will need to convert them using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(id), paid 
FROM `payments` 
WHERE paid IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(paid, '%e-%c-%Y')
```

Note you can ignore the time portion of the value when converting and so avoid the need for the `DATE` function.