# MYSQL GROUP BY with datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables like below:

a. table_order_detail

```
---------------------------------------------|
artnr | price | transactiondate     | deptnr |
---------------------------------------------|
1     | 1000  | 2020-01-23 01:30:11 | 1      |
1     | 1500  | 2020-01-24 23:43:24 | 1      |
3     | 2000  | 2020-01-24 12:31:52 | 1      |
```

b. table_article

```
----------------------|
artnr | cost | deptnr | 
----------------------|
1     | 500  | 1      |
2     | 700  | 1      |
3     | 1500 | 1      |
```

I want to show data with `GROUP BY` table_order_detail.transactiondate but with DATE only (like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column) ).

My SQL query is like below but not show data:

```
$sqldatanetrevenue = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DATE(table_order_detail.transactiondate) AS orderdate, table_order_detail.price, table_article.cost, table_order_detail.orderstatusitem
        FROM table_order_detail INNER JOIN table_article
        ON table_order_detail.artnr = table_article.artnr
        WHERE ((table_order_detail.deptnr='$departmentnr') 
        AND CAST(table_order_detail.transactiondate AS DATE) BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate')
        GROUP BY orderdate
");
```

But this query is work without `GROUP BY` :

```
$sqldatanetrevenue = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DATE(table_order_detail.transactiondate) AS orderdate, table_order_detail.price, table_article.cost, table_order_detail.orderstatusitem
        FROM table_order_detail INNER JOIN table_article
        ON table_order_detail.artnr = table_article.artnr
        WHERE ((table_order_detail.deptnr='$departmentnr') 
        AND CAST(table_order_detail.transactiondate AS DATE) BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate')
");
```

Assume $fromdate value is 2020-01-01 and $todate value is 2020-01-31. The second query show the data. But I want to group by date, but I don't know exactly what went wrong.

Expected result:

```
 -------------------------------|
 artnr | price | transactiondate|
 -------------------------------|
 1     | 1000  | 2020-01-23     |
 1     | 3500  | 2020-01-24     |
```

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: You are using a group by without any aggregate functions - you should not.

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce your issue once query 'fixed' to sum(cost) and sum(price) which is what I guess you were aiming for.

Comment: @D-Shih my expect result is data group by table_transaction_detail.transactiondate. My second query show the result but without grouping. But when I add Group By statement the result is empty.

Comment: Do not interpolate strings into your SQL queries! Use parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE() to extract only the date part from a datetime, aka:

```
SELECT DATE(your_date_field), count(*) 
FROM .. 
WHERE .. 
GROUP BY DATE(your_date_field)
```

Comment: I try this before but the query result still empty

Comment: You said you wanted to GROUP BY the date part of a datetime... and that is what it's doing. If your result is empty, check your WHERE condition. Remove the GROUP BY to see all results

Comment: as I said my second query is work but without grouping. So I want to group by them. I also tested my query without group by and show the result as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result is not related with the query you are trying.
When `GROUP BY` is used, the column in select statement  should be part of the group by clause or part of an aggregate function such as: `SUM(),MAX() ...etc`

Maybe you need something like:

```
select sum(price),
       date(transactiondate)
from table_order_detail
group by  date(transactiondate) ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> sum(price)    date(transactiondate)
> 1000           2020-01-23
> 3500           2020-01-24
> ```

If you need `artnr` you can add `MAX(artnr)`  to select the max value for each date, like below query:

```
select max(artnr),
       sum(price),
       date(transactiondate)
from table_order_detail
group by  date(transactiondate) ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> max(artnr) sum(price) date(transactiondate)
>     1       1000         2020-01-23
>     3       3500         2020-01-24
> ```

You can add the `join` , or `where` condition based on your needs.