# Hardcore sorting quest in mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sorting, group

I have a table "test":

```
ID | NAME | DATETIME
---+------+-----------------------
1  | a1   | 2023-05-01 01:00:00
2  | a2   | 2023-05-01 02:00:00
3  | a3   | 2023-05-01 03:00:00
4  | b1   | 2023-05-02 01:00:00
5  | b2   | 2023-05-02 02:00:00
6  | b3   | 2023-05-02 03:00:00
```

If I do a simple DESCend query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER by `DATETIME` DESC
```

I don't recieve exactly what I need. It returns 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ID's.
But how can I group my result by DATE and get a result sorted like that:

ID's in the desired result: **4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3**

As you can see, I need to sort each day by **time** ASC, but at the same time, starting from the last DATETIME.

I have no idea where to start and how to do such a request. Please help.

I tried to make temp arrays for each day by using PHP and resort them, but this is a bad decision, cause I also have a LIMIT 0, 20 in my query for page navigator, so it's bad at the end, cause it might be not a full day...

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/group-by-date-only-on-a-datetime-column#:~:text=Cast%20the%20datetime%20to%20a,mydate)%3B

Answer (score 1):

You need two terms in the `order by` clause - first descending by the date extracted from the datetime, and then ascending by the time extracted from it:

```sql
SELECT   * 
FROM     `test` 
ORDER BY DATE(`datetime`) DESC, TIME(`datetime`) ASC
```